# Finding the whole triangle information by one point.

Tags: analytic-geometry, triangles, 3d, polar-coordinates

I wonder if there's any way to blend two (or more) RGB colors in a reversible way? I mean, imagine we have an RGB pixel (R: 55, G:35, B:255), and we need to extract the two other RGB pixels that create this pixel when blended.

The point is that if we think of RGB as a cube (X=R, Y=G, Z=B), we can think of any RGB as a triangle within this cube. Is it possible to assign one point inside (or outside) this triangle and get the information of the other 3 RGB points in this triangle?

Comment: How does "blending" work in the first place?  If you are effectively adding two vectors together, or averaging two vectors together, then the answer is no.  For the same reason that just knowing that $x+y = 10$ you don't have enough information to know whether it was that $(x,y)$ was $(9,1)$ or $(8,2)$ or $(7,3)$ etc... so too can you not know for certain which colors were used in your blending process.  The "blending" transformation is a non-[injective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function), i.e. many-to-one, function which means that an inverse *cannot* exist.

Comment: That's exactly what's my question about: is there any way to present probably 3 points in a triangle, using only one point inside (or outside) it?

Comment: Short answer, no.  Longer answer, yes in real space but it wouldn't be implementable for your scenario since you are talking about discrete colors.  There are strictly more possible inputs than outputs.

Comment: What if I increase the size of the playing field? For example, distributing 65,535 colors manually within a field of 16 million points (i.e. 4096 x 4096 grid).

Comment: Then it could be invertible... but it being *meaningful* is an entirely different matter.  It certainly wouldn't correspond to any natural interpretation of "blending."  You wouldn't have any "nice" results like blue combined with blue gives blue.  Not to mention if your intention was to combine two rgb colors to get another *color* then your result wouldn't be in the right format.